# Enthusiast badge too enthusiastic?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, activity-badges

I noticed myself and others have begun receiving the [enthusiast badge](https://superuser.com/badges/39/woot-enthusiast) on superuser. As best I can tell, superuser launched on [July 15](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/) (see also [question 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1)). That puts the launch 29 days ago (considering today August 13, which it is in UTC); which means no one could receive the badge yet. Additionally, this supported by a quick click through to the profiles of many of the users' who have received this badge, which shows them as having accounts for 28 days (which I assume will be 29 when the cache updates for today). Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to look at the site before you logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inclusive - there are 30 days between July 15th and August 13th.

I can post the data we have for your SU user account, but I'm seeing 30 entries, including the 15th and the 13th.

Comment: I just received an Enthusiast badge for Apps and my profile page says I've been a member of that site for 28 days. I'd say that's *very* inclusive!

Answer (score 7):

Discussion on gaming badges has often popped up.

Looks like in this case...

*puts on sunglasses*

The badge as gamed **you**.

Comment: lol! +1, Horatio

Comment: YEEEEEEAAAAAAHHHHHH – http://xkcd.org/626/ *scnr*

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, you're right. I got my Enthusiast badge earlier today but I just assumed that it had been 30 days since it went live. In response to Brad Gilbert, I looked at the site for about 2 seconds before I signed up for my account, so there are no cookie issues (if that's what you're getting at).

Maybe Jeff is modifying the Enthusiast badge to be a little nicer by allowing people to miss at most 2 days? This might make those [going camping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13049/let-people-still-earn-the-woot-badge-if-they-register-for-a-holiday) sleep a little easier...

Comment: Seems unlikely to give a time allowance. Comparable to saying 'you only need 90 votes for a great answer'.