# Enthusiast badge in 28 days!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, activity-badges

I was recently awarded the [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280730/nvl) badge, while my profile shows I have been member for 28 days, instead of the required 30 for the badge.

[image]

P.S. I have been at SO for 30 days.

Comment: It's inclusive: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/enthusiast-badge-too-enthusiastic

Comment: @nvl: Ah, I misunderstood what you meant by "correct", thinking you were talking about the badge's requirements.

Comment: @random: thanks, the link explains the enthu.
@moderators: close this post, it has a dupe http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14124/enthusiast-badge-too-enthusiastic.

Comment: @gnome: i understood that you misunderstood, so i made it unambiguous. :)

Comment: @Jeff: how is it `status-norepro` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
User accessed site 6 hours ago (*.57.143)
User accessed site yesterday (*.57.143)
User accessed site 2 days ago (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 22 at 0:00 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 21 at 4:28 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 20 at 0:00 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 19 at 0:00 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 18 at 0:03 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 17 at 0:00 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 16 at 3:10 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 15 at 6:23 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 14 at 6:04 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 13 at 0:01 (*.57.143)
User accessed site Mar 12 at 6:05 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 11 at 2:33 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 10 at 2:47 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 9 at 0:33 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 8 at 4:15 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 7 at 2:28 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 6 at 0:48 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 5 at 0:22 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 4 at 0:00 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 3 at 0:01 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 2 at 0:07 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Mar 1 at 0:05 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Feb 28 at 0:06 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Feb 27 at 1:43 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Feb 26 at 0:35 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Feb 25 at 0:00 (*.4.49)
User accessed site Feb 24 at 21:57 (*.4.49)
```

I disagree; I count 30 rows here on your account.

Comment: :) Yes. I have been on SO for 30 days, but the profile shows 28 days.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is to be tracked back to February. That would have been a technically unintuitive calculation. It also actually doesn't calculate how long you've been a member. But it calculates how long you've visited SO consecutively and awards if it hits 30 days. Maybe this information is cookie-related and you've already visited SO 2 consecutive days before you registered yourself and became a member.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're just so darn golly enthusiastic!

Probably due to the differences in the way the badge algorithm calculates days vs the user page calculates days.

For instance, if you registered on day 1 right before the day change at midnight UTC then the badge calculation counts both day one immediately, and then a few minutes later, day 2.  However, the simple date calculation on the user page says, `joined on day one, it's currently day one, subtract, it's less than a day, figure out the hours, and the result is 0 days and x hours/minutes/etc` - there is now a difference of two days between the two methods of calculation.

Now we come to day 29, just after UTC switchover, and you are still two days different (29-1 days, plus some amount of hours =28) however, the badge test has switched to day 30, and it already counted day 1, so you've got thirty "stackoverflow time" days, while the userpage still uses the truncated hours (ie, there's no rounding on most time stamps on stackoverflow) current date minus start date (day 1 minus 28).

But until someone with access to the code, time, and a curiosity itch that won't go away peeks at it, there' sno way to know for sure.

Just be glad you are among the enthusiastic...  <sup><sub>or recognize your dependency and schedule an appointment with your mental health specialist...</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it is somehow related to the 28 day month of February. Whether the flaw is in the calculation of the badge, or the number on the profile, it can probably be tracked back to February.

Comment: We are down to only 10 months we can trust!

Comment: @Bill 9. September 1753 was only 17 days long.

Comment: ...this can't end well...

Comment: @Bill What was the other month?

Comment: @waiwai933: October, from earlier today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43865/what-does-careers-have-against-october  I guess I should have explained that. ;)

Comment: @Chacha102: Wikipedia says 1752 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1752

Comment: Here is the full conspiracy about February and October! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/why-we-cannot-trust-october-or-february-it-has-to-do-with-bacon

Comment: we can't trust November and December either, their names mean 9 and 10 but they're the 11th and 12th months.

Comment: @Quack -- that rules out anything after august.

Comment: @1 2: yes.  yes, it does.  and frankly, *July* looks pretty shifty too....